# Securely redirect to referer-header on logout

Tags: security, http

I am currently redirecting users back to where they came from on logout using the `referer` header.

Should I be concerned about the secureness of this approach when I am using SSL? I was first thinking about a MITM attack, but supposedly that shouldn't be too much of a worry with SSL on the sites.

Comment: "I am currently redirecting users […] using the `referer` header." u wot m8? Surely you mean `Location`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer - referer, right?

Comment: `Referer` is a header sent by the client to inform the server about the last visited location. If you wish to point the client to a new location, you normally want to use the [`Location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header.